# how to fix 404 not able to find Path in Rest API jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I am getting below error while testing Rest APi in jmeter

```
"status":404,"error":"Not Found","message":"No message available","path":"/api/get_user_by_id/"}
```

I have /api/get_user_by_id/ which i have added in Path and also i have added parameters Name as user and id as userid. When i run i get below response

And in Request i get `/api/get_user_by_id/?user=userid` instead it should be

```
/api/get_user_by_id/userid
```

How can i solve this ?

Comment: can you share jmeter screens and api link if possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of putting your `userid` into "Send Parameters With the Request" section just add it to "Path" of the [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler

[image: JMeter Send API request]

You might also need to add a [HTTP Header Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-http-header-manager) and configure it to send [Content-Type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type) header with the value of [`application/json`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#MIME_type)

Comment: I am able to get the result when i add userid directly to the Path. But if i have .csv file which has 100 users which tries to pick every user and check the response status is correct. In that case this way doesnt work.